# How to get the definition of a database trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, trigger, dmv, metadata

when I run the following script in one of my databases:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.triggers
```

[image]

when I try to find out about [sys.triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-triggers-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> Contains a row for each object that is a trigger, with a type of TR or
>   TA. DML trigger names are schema-scoped and, therefore, are visible in
>   sys.objects. DDL trigger names are scoped by the parent entity and are
>   only visible in this view.

How then, do I get the database triggers definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`OBJECT_DEFINITION()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Shameless copy and paste example from the docs:

> The following example returns the definition of a user-defined
>   trigger, uAddress, in the Person schema. The built-in function
>   OBJECT_ID is used to return the object ID of the trigger to the
>   OBJECT_DEFINITION statement.

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION (OBJECT_ID(N'Person.uAddress')) AS [Trigger Definition];   
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

how about

```
select m.definition from sys.triggers t
inner join sys.objects o on t.object_id = o.object_id
inner join sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = o.object_id
```

Comment: that works fine for the normal DML triggers, but it does not include the DDL triggers. Nice try though, deserves a +1

Answer (score 1):

I tried the [object_definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and it seems to work.

```
SELECT 
             object_id=s.object_id
            ,parent_name  = CASE WHEN s.parent_id = 0 THEN 'DATABASE' ELSE QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.parent_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.parent_id)) END

            ,trigger_name = CASE WHEN s.parent_class = 1 
                                 THEN QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id))
                                 ELSE S.name
                             END

            ,s.is_disabled
            ,THE_DEFINITION = object_definition(s.object_id)
            FROM sys.triggers s
```

[image]

example of copying an pasting of one of the database trigger definitions:

```
create trigger tr_MStran_alterview 
on database 
for ALTER_VIEW as  

set ANSI_NULLS ON         
set ANSI_PADDING ON         
set ANSI_WARNINGS ON         
set ARITHABORT ON         
set CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON         
set NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF         
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON           
declare @EventData xml         
set @EventData=EventData()           
exec sys.sp_MStran_ddlrepl @EventData, 2
```